# Prtg api filter all devices with certain tag

Tags: api, filter, prtg

I would like to filter all devices with certain tag. I'm unable to find right API call.
Could you please help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is

```
/api/table.json?content=sensors&columns=device,senors,tags, status,message&filter_tags=@tag(tagname)
```